# Taking the derivative of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

It is known that $$\det(A + \epsilon B) = \det A(1 + \epsilon tr(A^{-1}B) + O(\epsilon^2))$$

Taking $d/d\epsilon |_{\epsilon = 0}$ gives

$$d/d\epsilon |_{\epsilon = 0} \det(A + \epsilon B) =  tr(A^{-1}B)\det A$$

If $A = A(t)$, then to find $d/dt \det A $, it is supposed to be

$$d/dt \det A = \det A tr(A^{-1} d/dt  A)$$

Where is the $d/dt  A$ inside the trace coming from?  Are we supposed to set $B = I$?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement uses some abuse of notation. This is what it should look like:

Let $A(t)$ be a differentiable function defined on some open interval $I$, taking values in square matrices. Let $t_0$ be an element of $I$ and write $A_0 = A(t_0)$. Suppose that $A_0$ is invertible.

Then we have $$\frac d{dt}|_{t = t_0}\det A(t) = (\det A_0) \operatorname{tr}(A_0^{-1} \cdot \frac d{dt}|_{t = t_0} A).$$

To see this, write $\epsilon = t - t_0$ and hence $A(t) = A_0 + \epsilon \cdot \frac d{dt}|_{t = t_0} A + o(\epsilon)$. Then use your first statement with $A = A_0$ and $B = \frac d{dt}|_{t = t_0} A$.

You still need to argue that $\det(A_0 + \epsilon B + o(\epsilon)) = \det(A_0 + \epsilon B) + o(\epsilon)$ but this should be clear as $\det$ is essentially a polynomial.

Comment: DId you mean $o(\epsilon^2)$? Is it still trivia that the determinant of that series breaks down like what you have?

Comment: It's $o(\epsilon)$ with small $o$, i.e. the limit $\frac 1 \epsilon (A(t)  -(A_0 + \epsilon \cdot \frac d{dt}|_{t = t_0} A ))$ tends to zero when $\epsilon$ tends to zero.

Comment: I am not really familiar with little o. I thought we were just doing a series expansion on $A(t)$ at $t = 0$ so that $$A(t) = A(0) + tA'(0) + t^2A''(0)/2! + \dots$$, then take det on both sides $$\det A(t) = \det (A(0) + tA'(0) + t^2A''(0)/2! + \dots)$$

But I am not sure how to use the identity I posted on the RHS because it doesn't feel trivia to argue the RHS is a polynomial, so it breaks down linearly like $\det( A(0) + A'(0)t ) + t^2c_2 + \dots$

Comment: It may help to see an example. Let $A,B$ be $2\times 2$ matrices whose coefficients may be continuous functions of $t$. Expand $\det(A + tB) - \det(A)$ and try to convince yourself that the result tends to zero when $t$ tends to zero.

Comment: I've been comparing your statement with what is on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula and it appears the equality holds for all $t$. I am not doubting whether the quantity you wrote goes to $0$.